# auto_convert_lobs in Python is not working on cx_Oracle.Cursor object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I notice that the `auto_convert_lobs` argument does not work as expected if I am iterating a result using cx_Oracle.Cursor object.
From the documentation I read, cx_Oracle will convert Clobs into String by default : http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/oracle.html#lob-objects

The query I'm iterating is a function that returns a cursor instead of rows :

```
SELECT returns_a_cursor() FROM dual
-- pseudo code of returns_a_cursor():
FUNCTION returns_a_cursor() RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
sql := 'SELECT ...';
OPEN cursor FOR sql;
RETURN cursor;
```

The only reason I'm using a function instead of a direct query is only for readability and organization.

My python code looks like so

```
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://...')
conn = engine.connect()
result = conn.execute('SELECT returns_a_cursor() FROM dual').fetchone()
for row in result[0]:
    print row
```

This 'cursor' method will return my CLOB data types to cx_Oracle.LOB data instead of string.

If I change my code to execute a query without the function, it will be able to convert the CLOB data to string.

```
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://...')
conn = engine.connect()
result = conn.execute('SELECT a_clob_column FROM a_table')
for row in result:
    print row
```

Is there a way that I can keep the `auto_convert_lobs` setting in my use case ?

Comment: I encountered a case where i thought auto_convert_lobs is not working. But it was just a column datatype mismatch. The migration script created the column as LOB's. But my table metadata in sqlalchemy expected them as string. Could you check whether this is the same case as yours?

Comment: In my case, I don't use table metadata. It's a direct SQL query execution.

Comment: Oh. Maybe you can share what you did to make it work.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. My auto_convert_lobs works if I SELECT the Clob column directly, but it doesn't work if I iterate the value via Oracle's Cursor.

Comment: Have you tried [TextClause.columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=typemap#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextClause.columns)